# What are the Dinobots? (In regards to species)

Tags: transformers, dinobots

This question is about G1 canon.

The Transformers are called "Cybertronians", and they all have to have been created by the Quintessons, Primus, or Unicron. Cybertronians can make Cybertronians; Megatron said the Decepticons built the Constructicons, and it is revealed they did this on Cybertron in a later episode. They are in every way similar to other Cybertronians, other than being the first Combiner team.

The Dinobots are different. First, they were built by Wheeljack (not Shockwave) on Earth, so they could be called "Earthlings ". And, as seen in "*Desertion of the Dinobots*", they could function without Cybertonium unlike the other Cybertronians, implying that they are chemically different entirely.

So, could they be called Cybertronians in terms of species, or would they be called some other scientific name?

Comment: Are you asking specifically only about the cartoon continuity?

Comment: Additionally Megatron did *not* build the Constructicons. *The Secret of Omega Supreme* explains that the group that becomes the Constructicons existed already, and Megatron corrupted their programming as well as gave them the ability to merge into Devastator.

Comment: Related,not dupe based on my current understanding of the question: [Transformers - Origin of Dinobots (canon)](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/50215/5184)

Comment: G1 cartoon 1984 to 1987. And I remember Megatron saying this in the final episode of season 1 ( he used the term "we" not "I"). And the question is whether they should be considered an entirely different species, separate from Cybertronian entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They would still be considered Cybertronian despite being built on Earth. Keep in mind that building a new body, then bringing it to life, is the only way that Transformers can "reproduce".

A similar analogy would be if two Earthlings crash-landed on Mars, then conceived and had a baby. That baby, although born on Mars, would still be considered an "Earthling" by any native Martian. And although other Earthlings might consider the baby a "Martian", the rest of the universe would see it as just another Earthling.

It's important to note, however, that the G1 cartoon is unique in having the Dinobots created on Earth. Other continuities have the Dinobots originating on Cybertron itself.

Comment: Wait, what about the Dinobots being made out of entirely different materials and not needing cybertonium at all. (Still good answer)

Comment: To a Transformer, that's not really much different than the Martian kid having blue poop because he grew up eating Martian berries. There are several variations on the primary Transformer physiology, Dinobots would just be considered one variation.