# Why did the Autobots design the Dinobots to be stupid?

Tags: transformers

In Transformers, the Dinobots are said to have small brains just like real dinosaurs. But there was no point in doing that, if you could create them smart. If I recall correctly, Starscream created the Combaticons and while they might not be the smartest, they are smarter than the Dinobots. So, why couldn't the Autobots do something similar?

Why did the Autobots design the Dinobots to be stupid?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-aTbHsZJ9g

Comment: Because ***Roooooaaar!!!!!***

Comment: @FuzzyBoots lol,, I guess a lot of people thought the same

Comment: Also because 80s kids shows didn't need deep plots. Remember, this is the same company that [made a theatrical movie that killed some of the major characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transformers:_The_Movie) so they could release new toys

Comment: WJ: They're just like real dinosaurs. OP: explain WJ: they have simple brains OP: That's the most retarded thing I've ever heard WJ: What? I wanted them to be authentic . Huffer: Hey WheelJack, I bet real dinosaurs have metal skin too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is that [they were prototypes](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/S.O.S._Dinobots) with their brains built from scratch.

> Spike takes Hound on a tour of a natural history museum to further illustrate his paleontological crash-course. Hound snaps a few holograms of dinosaur bone displays, which he played back for the other Autobots. Wheeljack and Ratchet are inspired, believing that they could construct robot versions to use against the Decepticons, and Optimus gives them permission. A laborious construction ensues, based on designs drawn up on Teletraan I, with all of the Autobots taking part.

> Wheeljack unveils the three new additions to their ranks: the Dinobots Grimlock, Slag and Sludge. Impressed by the giant Dinobots and their ability to transform into dinosaurs, Optimus asks for a demonstration of their other abilities, and Wheeljack has them disintegrate the rubble from the earlier excavation. **As Wheeljack explains that he's looking to upgrade the Dinobots' limited intelligence**, the trio suddenly start attacking the Autobots. Grimlock heads for the control room, pursued by Bumblebee and Spike, but the pair are unable to prevent the Dinobot from trashing Teletraan I. Bumblebee does manage to lure Grimlock away from the room so Ratchet can start the long repair job. As the fight continues, Optimus orders the Dinobots destroyed, but Wheeljack manages to disable them with his magnetic inducer. Despite Wheeljack's pleas, Optimus orders them decommissioned, and the three Dinobots are sealed in the rock cavern, never to be activated again.

On the flip side, the [Combaticons](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Combaticon_(G1)) were built by Starscream by downloading existing Decepticon personalities into robot bodies.

> After bluffing his way past Skywarp and Thundercracker to use the space bridge, he travelled to a detention center on Cybertron and liberated the personality components of several Decepticon political prisoners before destroying the rest. Back on Earth, Starscream installed the components into the rusting military vehicles and ordered them to transform.

That's not getting into that [the continuity of the Dinobots is complicated](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50215/transformers-origin-of-dinobots-canon?noredirect=1&lq=1).